# The reference assemblies for framework v4.5 were not found

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am using VS 2012 and am working some projects for college. Thing is, debugger returns errors and warnings:

> "Warning  1   The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.

To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. GeometrijskeSlike"."

and also

> Warning   3 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
>   reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.  GeometrijskeSlike

and also

> Error 4   Source file 'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be
>   found C:\Users\Mladen\Desktop\GSlike\GeometrijskeSlike\GeometrijskeSlike\CSC  GeometrijskeSlike

Can someone help me with this, I just started C# and I am not very good at this...

Answer (score -1):

First You have to Install the Proper .Net Version that the project requires.
Once you have installed it. **Right click your Project** and go to **Properties**.
On the Application Tab, Choose the Targeted Framework to what the Project is requiring.

Next you have to choose the proper Build target platform. So probably the project is for x86 cpu or 32bit. Either way try both which one would work, because we can't tell from your project that if it is for x86 or 64 bit.

Go to Build Tab, Replace the **ANY CPU** to x86 first. If it doesn't work try 64bit.